# how to display two table records (selected column)

Tags: mysql

I created two tables:

```
Name:table1,table2

table1 consists of:id,name,contactnumber
                   101,john,9955443322
                   102,peter,9955443311
table2 consists of:id,place,date
                   101,chennai,15-05-2014
                   102,munbai,13-05-2014

select table1.id
     ,table1.contactnumber
     ,table2.date
from table1,table2
where table2.date = 29-09-2014
    && table2.loannumbers=table1.loannumber
```

But returned empty result set.

I want to display columns:

```
id,name,date
```

I want to display rows :

```
(table2)date=15-05-2014 and (table1)id=id(table2).
```

Comment: In your query you're using columns that are not listed in the provided table structures : `loadnumber`, is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use this syntax for jointures between tables. This is an old school notation and using explicit jointures will be much more readable.

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT T1.id
    ,T1.name
    ,T2.date
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2 ON T2.id = T1.id
                       AND T2.date = '2014-05-15'
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: got error Unknown column 'table1.contactnumber in 'field list'

Comment: @dsk i based my query on the table structures you provided. Can you confirm me that there is à column contactnumber in table1?

Comment: yes.contactnumber is  in mytable. i confused about error.

Comment: @dsk my query is well formed and matches the information you provided on your tables. If the error mention an unknown field, please check your structure and adapt the query if required

Comment: @dsk i replaced contactnumber by name in order to get the expected result. Can you test the query and tell me if everything is ok?

Comment: yes it worked . i wrote a query t1.contactnumber behalf of table1.contactnumber so error displayed.

Comment: @dsk don't forget to mark your question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name, table2.date 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id;
```